# android studio change font color of part of string in autocompletetextview arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

You'll see in the code below that I am concatenating 2 strings (strName and StrSciName) and adding the result to an arraylist which is added to an arrayadapter to be displayed in an autocompletetextview.

My question is: I would like to be able to display part of the text in italics in the autocompletetextview. So I would like strSciName (the part within [ ] ) to be in italics.

Is this possible?

Thank you

```
                final ArrayList<String> arrForAdapter = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String strName = jsonObject.getString("common_name");
                        String strSciName = jsonObject.getString("scientific_name");
                        String strVal = strName + " [ " + strSciName + " ]";
                        arrForAdapter.add(strVal);
                    }
                }  catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(actAddSighting.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrForAdapter);
                atvAnimalName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Via Spannable**

```
String strVal = strName + " [ " + strSciName + " ]";

Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(strVal);

spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), strName.length()+1, (strName+ strSciName).length()+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//Setting value on textview

myTextView.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

> NOTE: '+1' is included in start and end to include your brackets, it
>   can be     modified as per your need.

**2) Via HTML**

```
//Setting value on textview

myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" +YOUR TEXT));
```

> UPDATE: Seems like you have changed your question. As per change you
>   can try below code

```
SpannableString spannableString = SpannableString("String which needs in italic")
SpannableStringBuilder spannableBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()
spannableBuilder.append("OTHER STRING TO CONCAT")
spannableBuilder.append(spannableString, StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

myTextView.setText(spannableBuilder,TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I'm battling to find time to test fully, but at a glance it makes sense and looks like it'll do the trick. Thanks again. Regards,